# Change autosys job owner inside per script

Tags: sql-server, perl, autosys

Hi I encountered a problem.

Now I have an autosys job autosys_job, with job_owner = xyz. The autosys_job will call a perl script. Inside the perl script, I use MS SQL server's trusted authentication to log in to an SQL server:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:ODBC:driver={SQL Server};
                        Server=$server;
                        Database=$database;
                        Trusted Connection=yes", undef, undef);
```

The script will use account xyz to log in. However, xyz is not an authenticated account to log in to the SQL Server, in this case, I need the script to use another account abc to log in. How should I do that?

I tried modifying environment variable by

```
$ENV{USER} = abc
```

but it's useless.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing last two undefs with [user and pass](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#connect)